# Relay being switched on even though voltage not applied?

Tags: sensor, dc, solid-state-relay

**Introduction**

Firstly, I was not sure if the Home Improvement SE was appropriate for this or here, so if in wrong place I can post there instead.  So, what I am trying to do should be very simple to achieve. I have a series of stair lights that use motion sensors to turn them on. There are two sensors at the top of the stairs. Since the eye of one sensor "sees" too much (turns stairs on when I pass by the top), I want to wire it up so that the stairs will not turn on unless BOTH sensors at the top of the stairs see me.

**My attempt**

Below is the circuit I have created:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpGppD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Motion Sensor]

The [power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YF3FIFU), [motion sensors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E3NFOIW), [relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RTW33Z2) that I have used. The way I understand it, I provide the + to all lights, both + and - to turn the sensors themselves on, and then when either is tripped, they provide -. The relay in my mind should only turn on if sensor 1 is tripped.

**The Problem**

The problem is that when sensor 2 is tripped, it somehow turns the lights on. I am not sure how this is possible since the relay should not close the switch. I even verified with a multimeter and indeed the two output terminals are continuous even if nothing is hooked up to the relay input. How is this being tripped with no input??? How can I fix my circuit to get the desired effect I am after?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You can add in a proper schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid. Use the Custom Component if there isn't an appropriate symbol.

Comment: Add a link to the datasheet (not an Amazon or other ad page) for the sensors.

Comment: Your motion sensor wiring makes no sense if it works as just a switch. Why aren't they in series and only involving the relay coil? Why does sensor #2 it run off to the main contact instead of back to the transformer? And why does motion sensor 1 run back to the transformer instead of just to sensor #2?

Comment: @Transistor I have updated to include a schematic as you suggested. I am trying to find a data sheet for the sensors now

Comment: @DKNguyen I tried to wire them in a series but there was a delay to turn on the lights. I believe because the sensor that is behind the first didn't have initial power to turn itself on. The relay was to try and avoid this delay.

Comment: Do these motion sensors not have separate power inputs? How are they powered?

Comment: @DKNguyen There is a + and - input to turn the sensor on which allows it to start sensing, then if motion detected, it switches the output + and - to on.

Comment: The amazon page indicates that it is not a switch. It provides power to the load. So you need 2 relays, one driven by each switch with the relays' primary contacts in series with each other and the lights. You cannot connect the motion sensor outputs in series since they are power outputs, not switches so you need relays which you can connect in series.

Comment: @DKNguyen So if I understand correctly, I would connect the + and - outputs of the sensor to the corresponding inputs for the relays (one relay per sensor), then connect source - to first output of first relay, second output going to first output of relay 2, then last output to the lights?

Comment: If sensor output dry contacts, DPST relay, it should work.

Comment: Yes if i understood what you said. Just self post an answer with the new schematic and I'll tell you if it's right or mot.

Comment: @user263983 Amazon page indicated the sensor outputs provide power to the LEDs themselves, so acts more like a self-enabling power supply than simple switches

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank SO much for the help. Take a look at my answer. I believe this is what you were telling me

Comment: @DKNguyen What is self-enabling power supply? Sensor does not have power supply inside.You meant some transistor output?

Comment: The sensor output terminals aren't simple contacts. They actively provide power to the load (the motion sensor has power supply wires elsewhere). Just look at the diagram on the amazon page.

Comment: It looks like it says 12/24V presumably DC and not AC, so none of this makes sense.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Good point. The SSR says 60V max on the outputs. Does it even handle AC? I think OP is incorrectly using a transformer to represent the AC-DC power supply they linked. So it works in reality but the schematic symbols are wrong.

Comment: Sorry for not stating but yes I am converting 120v AC to 12v DC. I initially hooked up my relay like below and it seems to work. I just need to order a second relay to fully test.

Answer (score 1):

With **great** help from DKNguyen I will use two relays in series with the motion sensors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHXEHV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thus each sensor trips its own relay. If both relays are switched to on, then the - signal can go through to the lights.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @DKNguyen I will wire that up then! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are used SSR but schematic shows electromechanical relay. SSR for DC is MOSFET output, so the output polarity is important. You, probably, connected output terminals in reverse and internal diode conduct.

Comment: Yes, don't connect the relay "coil" the wrong way to the motion sensor output wires. Doesn't matter on an electromechanical relay but that's not what you have.

Comment: @DKNguyen  amazon page shows SSR with DC output. What coil are you talking about?

Comment: The coil on the electromechanical relay which doesn't actually exist and its equivalent on the SSR. Hence the quotes around coil.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are overcomplicating a dual-zone sensor. Just wire them effectively in parallel and block the undesired zone.**

Simply choose a material to hood or block the view of the upper sensor in the direction that it "sees too much".

Otherwise. it will only turn on when you get past or halfway down or up the stairs.

This assumes that the FET switch inside may be used as "Wired OR" logic to power the strip from the nearest end or both ends.  **It is more likely that Red is common to input and output** than black or both isolated.  But depending on wire length, you may need AWG 18 for long lengths to supply but not for a short length to strip.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did try to wire them in parallel like how you show but the problem is that there is about a 2 second delay when done this way (which is too long for moving your foot to the first stair). I believe this is because there is a very small "boot up time" for the sensor which is why I am trying with relays to leave the sensors "always on" to avoid that delay.

Comment: PIR's are always slow but very sensitive. Optical reflectors or interruptors work instantly with a 1 shot time out. They are always powered on here too. it's the output that is delayed